# Store Bitmap converted to byte array in Varbinary(MAX) or Image data type of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, arrays, varbinary, varbinarymax

I want to store image in a SQL Server database. I have converted image to byte array, and the data type of column in database is `varbinary(MAX)` but it didn't work even I have changed its type to `Image` but I get the same results.

I have followed many links from stackoverflow, code project, dream in code but couldn't find my solution there is my code for inserting byte array in database

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO myTable (ID, byteArray, DateTime) VALUES (@ID, @byteArray, @datetime)";

try
{
      command = new SqlCommand(query, base.conn);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@byteArray", ss); // ss is byte[] from arguments
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", DateTime.Now);

      base.Open();
      if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
      {
            base.Close();
            return true;
      }
      else
      {
             base.Close();
             return false;
      }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
      base.Close();
      return false;
}
```

I have also tried it with

```
command = new SqlCommand(query, base.conn);
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", id);
command.Parameters.Add("@byteArray", ss); // ss is byte[] from arguments
command.Parameters.Add("@datetime", DateTime.Now);
```

and the thing it will store in database

[image: The 3rd Column is of Image type and i am sending byte array in it]

but it will show the value in 3rd column as `<Binary data>` what is that???

Comment: @marc_s, that is the answer, if you posted that as-is I would have upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio will show `<binary data>` when some binary data (like a picture) is stored in that column. This is **works as designed**!

You won't actually see the picture itself in SQL Server Management Studio. I'm pretty sure your code works just fine - only your expectations of what Management Studio can do are too high ....

Comment: but how do i retrieve it so that i can convert it in Bitmap

Comment: @assassino: you just use a standard query to `SELECT` the data and get it back to your .NET application as a byte array / stream, which you can then feed into the `Bitmap` class ... but that's a whole different question agaiN!